# invalid subcommand: "upload" when using kubeadm to upload config

Tags: kubernetes

When I want to use kubeadm `kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.3", GitCommit:"ca643a4d1f7bfe34773c74f79527be4afd95bf39", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-07-15T21:03:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}` to upload a config file like this:

```
kubeadm config upload from-file --kubeconfig kubeadm-config.yaml
```

it give me error:

```
[root@k8smasterone config]# kubeadm config upload from-file --kubeconfig kubeadm-config.yaml
invalid subcommand: "upload"
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

I have read the kubeadm manual and did not find any replace with upload, what should I do to upload the config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it like this in new version:

```
kubeadm init phase upload-config kubeadm --config kubeadm-config.yaml
```

more info:https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/988